# Trying to use trap to break out of a shell function

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell function that will exit the function (but not the script) if an error occurs within it (specifically when a called command returns an error), and return an error code to the calling function.

As an example, for the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
on_error() {
    return 1
}

f() {
    echo 'function f'
    g
    echo "g returned $?"
}

g() {
    trap on_error ERR
    echo 'function g'
    false
    echo "boo"
}

f
```

I am getting back:

```
$ ./cc
function f
function g
boo
g returned 0
```

when I wish to be getting back:

```
$ ./cc
function f
function g
g returned 1
```

What do I need to do to get this?

If I change the on_error function to exit 1 like:

```
on_error() {
    return 1
}
```

then I get:

```
$ ./cc
function f
function g
```

to indicate that the whole script is exiting when it hits the 'false' command.

While it would be possible in this example case to simply check the error code of the commands inside of g and return an error if one of them fails, in my real case I want a test function to attempt to copy a dozen or more files from different locations to different destinations and stop the first time that one of them fails so that I can report a test failure and go on to the next test function.

Though I would prefer a /bin/sh solution, /bin/bash would be good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? (Bash only.)

```
#!/bin/bash

f() {
    echo 'function f'
    g
    echo "g returned $?"
}

g() {
    trap 'return 1' ERR
    echo 'function g'
    false
    echo "boo"
}

f
```

Comment: I don't know yet why, but `trap return ERR` is enough.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the returning of values from trap. 'trap return ERR', 'trap "return 1" ERR', and 'trap "return 50" ERR' will all return 1. On the other hand, I can do a 'trap "echo $LINENO;return 1" ERR' and get the line number of the false command and a return of 0 although it does exit the function without echoing "boo".

Comment: The `return` in trap seems transparent. Ie. it returns the return value of whatever is before it. If it's alone the return value 1 comes form the error, I gather. Otherwise, it's the last command. So effectively, to return 1 after a 0, this needs to be done: `trap 'echo $LINENO; false; return' ERR`.

Comment: Btw, with $LINENO you need to use the single quotes `'`, otherwise Bash will expand the value at the line of it's declaration.